Cookies Cross-Origin Working on Desktop But Not on Mobile (Express.js, Railway, Vercel)
I'm building an application where the frontend (React.js) is hosted on Vercel, and the backend (Express.js) is on Railway. The authentication mechanism is based on cross-origin cookies, which are set after the user logs in. The issue I'm facing is that cookies work perfectly fine on desktop browsers (both Chrome and Safari), but they do not work on mobile devices (Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android).
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const { CLIENT_BASE_URL } = require("./utils/config");
const postRoutes = require("./routes/postRoutes");
const productRoutes = require("./routes/productRoutes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// Middleware

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: CLIENT_BASE_URL,
    credentials: true,
  })
);

// Routes
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoutes);
app.use("/api/products", productRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);

// Listening to server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

utils/config.js
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

const config = { development: { CLIENT_BASE_URL: "http://localhost:3000",   }, production: { CLIENT_BASE_URL: "https://mydomain.vercel.app", <-- here i have my domain   }, };

module.exports = { CLIENT_BASE_URL: config[environment].CLIENT_BASE_URL, JWT_SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET || "supersecretkey", TOKEN_EXPIRATION: "1h", };

login with res.cookies:
exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // Validate input
  const { error } = loginSchema.validate(req.body);
  if (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: error.details[0].message });
  }

  try {
    console.log("Incoming data:", req.body);

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      console.log("User not found");
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Nieprawidłowe dane logowania" });
    }

    console.log("Stored hashed password:", user.password);

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      console.log("Password does not match");
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Nieprawidłowe dane logowania" });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { userId: user._id, role: user.role },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      {
        expiresIn: "1h",
      }
    );

    res.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production", // Ustaw `true` tylko dla HTTPS w środowisku produkcyjnym
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax", // Użyj "None" w produkcji (dla cross-origin), "Lax" w lokalnym środowisku
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 dzień
     
    });

    res.removeHeader("Vary");

    console.log("Nagłówki odpowiedzi po logowaniu:", res.getHeaders()); // Logowanie nagłówków odpowiedzi

    const userWithoutPassword = {
      _id: user._id,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      role: user.role,
      // Dodaj inne pola, jeśli potrzebujesz
    };

    res.json({ message: "Zalogowano pomyślnie", user: userWithoutPassword });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during login:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Błąd podczas logowania", error });
  }
};

In Axios FRONTEND, I always set withCredentials: true:
Is there anything specific I need to do to make cross-origin cookies work in mobile browsers like Safari on iOS or Chrome on Android? I’m wondering how major platforms handle cross-origin cookies to ensure they work across all browsers and devices.
Any help or suggestions on how to effectively solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
What I Have Tried:
Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin dynamically based on the Origin header from the request.
Ensuring HTTPS is used in production and the cookie is set with secure: true.
Adding CORS headers for every request (including OPTIONS) and ensuring that Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is always set to true.
Debugging on mobile devices:
Used Web Inspector on Safari and Remote Debugging in Chrome on Android – the cookie is set but is not sent with subsequent requests.
